# Seating Arrangement puzzle.

Tags: puzzle

Not sure if its a correct place to post these kind of questions.

Eight persons-P,S,Q,R,U,B,J and C are sitting in a field in a circle.

Three are facing opposite side and other five are facing the centre. S is sitting to the third right of B. R is not near C. Q is sitting to the third left of R, who is second right of P,and among these three ,one is facing opposite to the centre of circle. Two are sitting between C and U and two are sitting between B and U. Q is sitting to the second left of J, who is facing the centre of the circle S is facing the centre of the circle. U is not opposite to B and Q.

I am able to get the position of persons in the circle but not able to find the direction in which they are facing.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I get multiple solutions (including two different positions for the people), so either I'm not reading the problem correctly or there is missing information.

Here's how I'm reading things.  Three people are facing *outward* and five are facing *inward*.  "R is not near C" means they're not sitting next to one another.  "U is not opposite to B and Q" means if B and Q are facing in the same direction (either inward or outward), then so is U.

Here is one solution, with the people listed in *counter*-clockwise order and Uppercase letters for the five facing inward and lowercase letters for the three facing outward:

$$\text{CQbJPurS}$$

Here are the other two:

$$\text{CQbJRupS}\\
\text{cQbJRUpS}$$

(Note that the latter two solutions have people sitting in the same positions, but with C/u in one and c/U in the other.)

One way to check these solutions is to imagine Uppercase letters facing up, and lowercase letters facing down, with wrap-around at the ends.  Thus, for example, b is looking down, so Q is to his immediate right, C (or c) two positions to b's right, and S is *third* right of b.

Ideally I would draw a picture of each solution.  If someone would like to do so for me, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

While the order of seating is CSQUJRBP, the directions cannot all be determined from the info given.  For example, two possible and different solutions would be BQ and C facing outward, or RU and C facing outward.

Comment: I get a contradiction when I try checking your solution.  Can you take a look at my answer and tell me if I'm missing something?  (For one thing, are you listing people in clockwise or counter-clockwise order?)

Answer (score 0):

There is a single answer to this question. First get the definite thing going. Q sits second to the left of J, J faces inward. Then position CBU. U cannot be opposite to BQ, after trying to position them I found that the only place where B can sit is opposite to Q. This is because there has to be a gap of 2 places between i.e. B--U & C--U and with any other combination this does not work. After placing them move onto placing R, it cannot be near C, so only one place left. Then position P, and out of PQR one has to be looking outside & it has to be P.
S looks inward (given) and only U apart from PC looks out. Therefore CPU look out and SQJRB look in. Happy puzzling guys!

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding in what order people are seated around the table in your answer.